# Android Studio - External Libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've two computers,say A and B. I've complete source code of my Android Application which i am building in Android Studio 1.2.1.1 in my computer A. Now, I've to work in computer B also. So, I've installed Android Studio in my computer B and copied the source code to B and loaded into the Android Studio. Everything went fine, but it's saying that `Failed to resolve myexternallibraries` which i've in the `\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar` directory.but the Android Studio is not taking those directories into account.

I know that this error can be solved by re-downloading those libraries again, but i want to know if there's any **OFFLINE SOLUTION** to this problem.

Comment: Try cutting the jar and remove every thing associated with it in gradle and try to do it again

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get what you mean by `cutting the jar`.

Comment: Cut copy and paste one

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: Please post the gradle file

Answer (score 0):

try changing the dependencies in your gradle.build . For example

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.3.jar')
}
```